# Watching UK TV though a proxy server in the US through the Wii

Tags: proxy, tv, wii

I have everything set up and can watch BBC on my PC through my proxy server.

When I try and stream through the Wii, I get to the correct page, click on the PLAY arrow...and wait.....nothing.  I don't get an error message so it seems the proxy server is working.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm going to close this because it is off-topic in several areas...It is subjective/argumentative, the proxy server is illegal (probably, don't quote me), and we don't really discuss Wii's here...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the iPlayer app from the Wii shop?